# PCRE Regex for Email Addresses

Tags: regex, pcre

I try to create an PCRE regex to capture email addresses **from a large bulk of text**. The current regex I came up with is:

```
(?:[^\w]|^)([a-z0-9+_\-\.]+[^\.]@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9])?)(?:[^\w]|$)
```

This regex is just too slow (side Q, why is it that slow? is it the non captured groups that heavy on the performance?). I understand that there will be some trade off between coverage of all valid emails and performance, I aim to get the most common formats, like:

```
very.common@example.com
disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com
other.email-with-hyphen@example.coma
fully-qualified-domain@example.com
user.name+tag+sorting@example.com
example-indeed@strange-example.com
mailhost!username@example.org
user%example.com@example.org
```

But not invalid addresses like:

```
Abc.example.com
A@b@c@example.com
A.....example.com
```

So for instance A@b@c@example.com is invalid, but I don't want the regex to catch A@b@**c@example.com** "c@example.com" also!
I tried to approach Negative lookahead to check for example any existence of @ for example (?

Comment: It is a bit broader match, but you might try it with `(?<!\S)[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@.]+(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/CTw01I/1

Comment: [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). The best way to validate an email address is to send a  message and check the return value.

Answer (score 2):

I think you make it too complex. I would simplify the regex in the following way:

```
[-_a-zA-Z0-9.+!%]*@[-_a-zA-Z0-9.]*
```

If you don't want to match emails with uppercase chars, you just change `a-zA-Z` into `a-z`. I added the underscore `_` as char that can be present in the address.

If you consider that an address may not begin with a char inside of the range `-_+!%`, you could add some complexity to the regex, but I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: What about `myname123@whatever`

Comment: @Toto `myname123@whatever` will be validated. The PO didn't put it as an example of invalid pattern. It is possible to impose the presence of at least one dot after the `@` complexifying the regex as follows: `[-_a-zA-Z.+!%]*@[-_a-zA-Z]*\.[-_a-zA-Z.]*`.

Comment: I just said you doesn't accept digits in the name part.